# Variables in Power BI measure

Tags: expression, powerbi, dax, measure

I tried this measure in Power BI:

```
Own_Damage_OS =
VAR VpeDate = [VpeDate]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( OS_excel[OS_AMOUNT] ),
        Claims_excel[COVER_NAME] = "Own Damaage",
        Premium_Excel[LOB] = "MOTOR",
        OS_excel[AS_OF_DATE] = VpeDate
    )
```

[image: result]

but the problem is that when I called this `OS_excel[AS_OF_DATE]=VpeDate`, this shows the same figures in every date like this

but the actual result is this

[image: actual result]

Is there any solution?

this is power bi file link please download

https://www.dropbox.com/s/94mj2uebvlmqqep/Claims1.pbix?dl=0

Comment: Is `[VpeDate]` a measure? How is it calculated?

Comment: no this is not measure..

Comment: in this measure i set date like this "VpeDate = date(2017,12,31)" so when i drag this into sheet and user change date then according to date change data will be displayed .. i also attached sample Power bi file e.. kindly check

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it that way because of [contexts](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/row-context-and-filter-context-in-dax/). And you actually don't need to. Just remove the date part from measure, put the measure into canvas and slice (put it into visual to axis field) it via the date field .

Thing to note: you need to have proper relationship between the tables. If you don't know how to do so, please share sample data, so we can help you further.

Comment: Kindly check power bi file .. i paste dropbox link

Comment: As noted in answer, all you need to do is remove the date part from the measure, ie make it: 

Own_Damage_OS_working = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( OS_excel[OS_AMOUNT] ),Claims_excel[COVER_NAME]="Own Damaage",
   Premium_Excel[LOB] = "MOTOR"
   
)
And ull get desired output: